# Simple Regex Substituion

Tags: regex, bash

How can I make a simply regex substitution for:

`0x` > `0x0`

I've tried using sed and perl... but regex is my weak side.

```
echo $1 | perl -pe '0x and 0x0'
#$1 being first argument to function
```

Tried this but I get an empty echo.

Comment: show what have you tried so far

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Added one of my attempts, the latest one.

Comment: `echo "${1//0x/0x0}"`

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's one way:

```
perl -pe 's/0x/0x0/g'
```

If this runs into problems, you'll have to be specific. For instance, you might want to avoid replacing `0x0` with `0x00` with a regex such as:

```
perl -pe 's/0x0?/0x0/g'
```

Comment: Either it's because I'm answering a simple question (people get mad about that) or it's the use of perl :P

Comment: I know this is not what the comments is for, but thank you.

Answer (score -2):

Don't use `perl`. It's like shooting fly with cannon. Use `sed`

```
echo $1 | sed -e 's/0x/0x0/g'
```